# Sharing array between two processes

Tags: c++, arrays, winapi, memory

I have an array that I need to share between two processes.  The first process has an injected DLL that constantly grabs info about a few objects, and the second process needs to receive this information.  I constantly update this array (the data in the object changes a lot), and the other process needs to constantly receive these updates.  I've seen examples where people use shared memory, but I'm not sure how I could use it to constantly update the array.  Any advice or code you can throw at me?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [memory mapped file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx) to share your array among several processes.

Comment: I've seen that solution, but it looks like updating the data on that file might be slow.  I update the array data very quickly.  Wouldn't updating the file constantly be slow?

Comment: Generally, the file I/O is cached in MMF to improve system performance. The update to the array is written to the RAM, not necessarily the disk.

Comment: It's an array of 2048 structs that are about 32 bytes in size.  If I really needed to, I could shorten that array down to 255 or 64, but that would mean killing functionality to my program.

Comment: It is updated in a while loop in another thread in the target process.

Comment: @user1822632: Well that's the most straightforward solution, so how about you try it out and see if it works for you?

Comment: Go to MMF It's for that kind of usage. And 2048*32 byte=64ko it's pretty small system will cache it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can share data in a DLL between processes that load that DLL. See [How do I share data in my DLL with an application or with other DLLs?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for details on how to use `#pragma data_seg` to do this. So if you store the array in your DLL and both processes open the DLL, all you need is some sort of synchronisation (e.g. a mutex) to arbitrate shared access to the data.

For convenience you would probably want to implement exported functions in the DLL to read/write the array data rather than exporting the raw array itself.

Comment: Because of the nature of the process I am injecting in (video game with anticheat), I had to inject the dll in a way that really doesn't make it a DLL.  I'm using the DLL for it's PE header so I can handle relocating everything and importing dependencies that might exist.  I then map the dll minus the PE header into the remote process, and then execute the main thread function (not dllmain, since dllmain only executed the main thread as well).